# How to pass object as component input in ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to iterate over an array of Audio objects (contains 3 strings) and passing the audio in each iteration to a child component.

**app.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit(){
    this.audios = new Array<SoundBoardAudio>();
    this.audios.push(new SoundBoardAudio('Western','La canción del Sheriff.','western.mp3'));
    this.audios.push(new SoundBoardAudio('Olvidelo Amigo','Busquese otro tonto amigo.','olvidelo_amigo.mp3'));
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="container">
   <app-soundcard *ngFor="let audio of audios" soundBoardAudio=audio></app-soundcard>
</div>
```

**soundboard.component.ts**

```js
export class SoundcardComponent implements OnInit {

  audio:any;

  constructor() {}

  @Input() soundBoardAudio;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.soundBoardAudio);
    let audioSrc = 'assets/audio/'+this.soundBoardAudio.filename;
    this.audio = new Audio(audioSrc);
  }
...
```

**soundboard.component.html**

```html
<div class="card" >
  <div class="card-block">
    <h2 class="card-title">{{soundBoardAudio.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{soundBoardAudio.desc}}
  </div>
</div>
...
```

But when I try to read the audio from the child component, I get an undefined value. If I only pass a string instead of an object, it works ok.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your input syntax is not correct inside parent html. Do like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <app-soundcard *ngFor="let audio of audios" [soundBoardAudio]="audio"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I did that and it solved my problem which was passing data as `[object] [object]` because it would get casted as a string (I was iterating a parent element and passing data to a child component), however when I inspect the child component I can see `ng-reflect-data="[object Object]`.

is this normal? I am passing an object.

Comment: Well `ng-reflect-data` is only there for debugging purpose. It shows all bindings on component which is actually a object of properties that are part of your component (class)

Comment: Alrighty, I appreciate the information. I also found it very weird that I had to bind the data on the same element on which I was iterating, originally I wanted to iterate on an `<ion-row>` and pass the array element to `<ion-col>` (the child component)

Comment: Well that is weird. Only explanation for that is that ion component is created that way to read from parent inputs so no need to bind it any lower.

Answer (score 1):

In your parent component

```
<div *ngFor="let pollData of PollList ; let i index" >            
    <app-pollinfo [masterArray]="i"></app-pollinfo>
</div>
```

in your child component

```js
@Input() masterArray : any;
```

use this and pass index then you will get data as object.